# Practices for a fast drop_duplicates() in Dask

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dask

I read CSV files from an AWS bucket using Dask. I want to drop duplicates from a big data-frame.

The number of partitions is 755,286 and the number of tasks is 1,510,572.

I'm wondering what could be a faster way to drop duplicates from the data-frame.

Here's my code:

```
df = dd.read_csv(s3_path, storage_options = {'key': key, 'secret': secret})

df = df.drop_duplicates(['X'])

df = df.compute()
```

Comment: Unless someone who knows the Dask internals comments, it's hard to know exactly. If you can break up your DataFrame to independent partitions where there will not be any duplicates across partitions, you can try map_partitions + pandas drop_duplicates to speed this up. But I expect Dask would do that already when you subset based on a column. Do you have something with high cardinality? You can try groupby-idxmax and then merging back to the original DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion in @Kevin Kho's comment might help even if there are duplicates across partitions: a combination of `map_partitions` and `pd.drop_duplicates` can potentially trim down the content of each partition.

If the data is shuffled across partitions in a way that requires a lot of communication between `755,286` partitions, I'd go back to the original problem and check whether I'm using the appropriate data chunking strategy for it.